# Can 3D co-ordinates be transferred into 2D co-ordinates?

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, laplace-transform, transformation, plane-geometry

Is it possible to transform co-ordinates $(a,b,c)$  into $(x,y) $ such that $(x,y)$  is unique for each $(a,b,c)$ ? $a, b,  c,  x,  y$ are in $\Bbb{R}$ .

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the map from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$ to be invertible, or just exist? As BJKShah, the former is possible but not if it's linear, whereas the latter is possible even then (such a map is an example of a projection).

Comment: I want the conversion to be possible in both directions.( How to convert former as you said , any links?) Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's is possible to have a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, since it can be shown that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, and hence every $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the same cardinality.  But a linear or affine isomorphism is not possible if the dimensions are different.

Comment: Can you please explain the last sentence a bit more?

Comment: Right. A map f:R^n\to R^m will be linear if f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v) and f(au)=af(u) for all scalars a and vectors u,v. We can show that if such an f is a bijection, then m=n. This follows from what is called the Rank Nullity Theorem.  An affine map is of the form f+c, for a linear map f and a constant vector c. Again if an affine map is bijective, then we can show that m=n.

Comment: Any good books for studying this?

Comment: Calculus and Analytic Geometry by Thomas and Finney, for coordinate geometry, and Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang for linear algebra.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but it's not pretty, and as VENKITESH says, it's certainly not linear. Here is one way: define $$f(a,b,c)=(x,y)$$ where $x=a$, and $y$ is the *alternating decimal expansion* of $b$ and $c$. What that means is this:

Take the non-terminating decimal expansions of $b$ and $c$; if necessary, insert leading zeroes so that the integral parts have the same length. For instance, if $b=1234.345$ and $c=76.987698798\ldots$, we convert $b$ to its non-terminating form $b=\color{red}{1234.344999999\ldots}$, and we write $c$ as $\color{blue}{0076.987698798\ldots}$ to make the lengths before the decimal point equal.

Now we can write $y$ by taking digits from $b$ and $c$ in turn:

$$y=\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{0}\color{red}{2}\color{blue}{0}\color{red}{3}\color{blue}{7}\color{red}{4}\color{blue}{6}.\color{red}{3}\color{blue}{9}\color{red}{4}\color{blue}{8}\color{red}{4}\color{blue}{7}\color{red}{9}\color{blue}{6}\color{red}{9}\color{blue}{9}\color{red}{9}\color{blue}{8}\color{red}{9}\color{blue}{7}\color{red}{9}\color{blue}{9}\color{red}{9}\color{blue}{8}\ldots$$

This is just one way. By the way, the name *alternating decimal expansion* is something I just made up, so don't take it too seriously.

**Edited to add:** I see you changed your criteria in a comment. This mapping is an injection, but not a surjection, so it doesn't have an inverse. You can make it surjective, but it's messy, and I'm not going to do it here.

**Edited to add:** As the OP points out in a comment, I have not define the mapping for $b,c\le 0$. My bad! But you can fix this by using the decimal expansions of $e^b$ and $e^c$, which are always strictly greater than zero.

Comment: (1,2,1)=(1,21) but (1,-2,-1) and (1,-2,1)=(?) Thanks for the example.